# how to insert a linked list after a particular node inside head? c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, head

I wrote the following code to insert an integer to a linked list, but in a sorting approach.

I commented where my problem is and explained it below:

```
void LLL::insertSorted(int r) {
    node * temp = NULL;
    node * current = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new node;
        head->data = r;
        head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        temp = new node;
        temp->data = r;
        current = head;
        while (temp->data > current->data && current != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        temp->next = current;
        /* 
         * Assume that I have head points to this list: { 3 -> 5 -> 8 -> NULL }
         * And I want to insert {6} (temp) to the list just after 5; then what 
         * I've done so far on my previous code I made temp = {6 -> 8 -> NULL}.
         * NOW!! How can correctly insert temp to ((head)) just after {5}??!
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a previous tem when you travel the link, add previous = current; before current = current->next; after temp->next = current; add previous->next = temp;

Comment: @JerryChen I've added what you suggested to my snippets. Is this what you mean? If yes, how it is going to change my head?

Comment: 1. empty list 2. smallest number

Comment: @JerryChen would you explain more? I am new to this concept, and I understand code better than words

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember which node you are inserting after, and have that node link to the new one.

For example, in your loop to find the node that comes after `temp`, `current`, have another variable, say `prev`, and do `pre = current` just before `current = current->next`.

Comment: would you show me how exactly using my code snippets?

Comment: do you mean by having a previous node dereferencing {5}, and making previous->next = temp?

Answer (score 0):

```
void LLL::insertSorted(int r) {
    node * cur = head;
    node * prev = NULL;

    while((cur != NULL) && (r > cur->data)){//find the location to insert
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    node *new_node = new node;
    new_node->data = r;
    new_node->next = cur;

    if(prev == NULL){//new first one
        head = new_node;
    }else{
        prev->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this going to change my head? would you explain?

Comment: so you only need to change your head when the list is empty, or when the number that you want to insert in the smallest. If the list if empty, then "new_node" is (num, empty), and we assign this new_node to head. Otherwise (when list is not empty, and the number you are trying to insert is the smallest), "while loop" part in the code will not be executed since num(r) < cur->data), so new_node now is (num, cur(previous head)), and we assign this new_node to head

Comment: @Soce1991 Does above comment help you better understand?

Comment: yeah but I think I've already done that to my code above, don't you agree?

Comment: @Soce1991 the code you wrote in the answer section seems good to me, but it's just not clean. Try to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

you need a new node when insert
 I think just make a new node after the previous one you want insert, like 5 in your comment

Comment: Would you apply that to my code so I can understand better what you mean and I can mark it as answer so others can find the solution?

Comment: if you don't want to change your link list to a double link list, you can try to change your `while(temp->data > current->data && current != NULL)` to `while(temp->data > current->next->data && current != NULL)` , that will make the "6" compare with 8, not 5, and it will insert after 5, not before 8, you need not add a "previous" node, just "next", sorry my English is bad

Comment: your english is fine, but I understand code better. So, if you could use my code to fix the problem then, we don't need english

Comment: thanks, I think you can try this way without change other code you have written, just this while statement, because what you write is "insert before" not "insert after":)

Answer (score 0):

This is the final result: (it works!)
It handles the following cases:

- case 1: head is empty.
- case 2: the new element is the smallest in the list.
- case 3: the new element is somewhere in the middle of the list.
- case 4: the new element is the largest.

```js
void LLL::insertSorted(int r) {
    node * temp = NULL;
    node * current = NULL;
    node * previous = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new node;
        head->data = r;
        head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        temp = new node;
        temp->data = r;
        temp->next = NULL;

        current = head;
        if (temp->data < current->data) {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        } else {
            while (current != NULL && temp->data >= current->data) {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            temp->next = current;
            previous->next = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The insert function below seems to be OK. Check the constructor of Node and List.

Comment: @JerryChen it works if I change the 2nd part of the loop condition to (current->next != NULL), BUT THIS SKIPS THE FIRST INPUT if I entered {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5} I get {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}! Do you know what is the problem? and how to fix it. (please answer with code, little english)